# Tkinter - Optionmenu - Is it possible to change the indicator arrow when the dropdown box is clicked by the user?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I have managed to change the indicator within the optionmenu box through using `indicatoron=0, compound=RIGHT, image=dropImg, width=120` but I am now trying to change the arrow to point up when the box is clicked and the list of elements are shown.
For instance:
I tried `activeindicatoron = 0` but this doesn't work. Does anyone have any ideas on whether this is possible in tkinter?

Thanks, Jacob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. For instance, you can

1. Use the `postcommand` option of the Optionmenu's menu to change the image on the button to an arrow pointing up.
2. Use a binding to the `<Unmap>` event of the Optionmenu's menu to revert to the arrow pointing down when the menu disappears.

Here is an example:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()

# up and down images
down =b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x07\x08\x06\x00\x00\x008G|\x19\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x01t\x89\x9cK\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x00OIDAT\x18\x95\x95\xce\xb1\x0e@P\x0cF\xe1\xefzI\x8fc$\x12\x111\x19\xec\x9e\x12\xcb\x95 A\x9d\xa4K\xff\x9e\xb6\t\x13J\xffX \xa1\xc7\x16\xac\x19\xc5\xb1!*\x8fy\xf6BB\xf7"\r_\xff77a\xcd\xbd\x10\xedI\xaa\xa3\xd2\xf9r\xf5\x14\xee^N&\x14\xab\xef\xa9\'\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
up = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x07\x08\x06\x00\x00\x008G|\x19\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x01t\x89\x9cK\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x00\\IDAT\x18\x95\x8d\xd0A\n\x830\x14\x06\xe1/z,\x0f\xd2#\x19\\\xb4\x08Ep\xe1\xbe\xd7\xe8\xc5\xd2n\x12\x11%\x92\x81\xd9<\xfe\xd9\xbc^\x9d\x88\x01\xdf\x9b\xcd\x85\t?$\x8c\xadQ\xccQ1\xe5[\x95\x80\xe7)::\xd7\xa2\xd7MT|\xe7\xed\x1e-\rQqC\x17\xb0\xe2\xd1\xfa\x80\xcc\xe7\x0fO\xbe&\x9dv\xae\xef\x97\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
imgDown = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, data=down)
imgUp = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, data=up)

# create option menu
var = tk.StringVar(root, 'a')
option = tk.OptionMenu(root, var, *list('abcde'))
option.configure(indicatoron=0, compound=tk.RIGHT, image=imgDown, width=120)

# configure menu
menu = option['menu']
menu.configure(postcommand=lambda: option.configure(image=imgUp))
menu.bind('<Unmap>', lambda ev: option.configure(image=imgDown))
option.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**TTK version**

It is also possible to achieve this when using a `ttk.OptionMenu` and I think it look nicer because the arrow really replaces the indicator instead of being in the place of the image. This can be done by modifying the layout of the `TMenubutton` style:

1. Create 'up' and 'down' elements from the images

   ```
   style.element_create('up', 'image', imgUp)
   style.element_create('down', 'image', imgDown)
   ```
2. Create 'up.TMenubutton' and 'down.TMenubutton' layouts from the 'TMenubutton' layout (obtain with `style.layout('TMenubutton')`) by replacing 'Menubutton.indicator' by 'up' or 'down'.
3. Use `postcommand` and `<Unmap>` to change the style of the Menubutton.

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
root = tk.Tk()

# images
down = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x07\x08\x06\x00\x00\x008G|\x19\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x01t\x89\x9cK\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x00OIDAT\x18\x95\x95\xce\xb1\x0e@P\x0cF\xe1\xefzI\x8fc$\x12\x111\x19\xec\x9e\x12\xcb\x95 A\x9d\xa4K\xff\x9e\xb6\t\x13J\xffX \xa1\xc7\x16\xac\x19\xc5\xb1!*\x8fy\xf6BB\xf7"\r_\xff77a\xcd\xbd\x10\xedI\xaa\xa3\xd2\xf9r\xf5\x14\xee^N&\x14\xab\xef\xa9\'\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
up = b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x07\x08\x06\x00\x00\x008G|\x19\x00\x00\x00\tpHYs\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x00\x00\x10\x9b\x01t\x89\x9cK\x00\x00\x00\x19tEXtSoftware\x00www.inkscape.org\x9b\xee<\x1a\x00\x00\x00\\IDAT\x18\x95\x8d\xd0A\n\x830\x14\x06\xe1/z,\x0f\xd2#\x19\\\xb4\x08Ep\xe1\xbe\xd7\xe8\xc5\xd2n\x12\x11%\x92\x81\xd9<\xfe\xd9\xbc^\x9d\x88\x01\xdf\x9b\xcd\x85\t?$\x8c\xadQ\xccQ1\xe5[\x95\x80\xe7)::\xd7\xa2\xd7MT|\xe7\xed\x1e-\rQqC\x17\xb0\xe2\xd1\xfa\x80\xcc\xe7\x0fO\xbe&\x9dv\xae\xef\x97\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82'
imgDown = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, data=down)
imgUp = tk.PhotoImage(master=root, data=up)

# style
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')
style.element_create('up', 'image', imgUp)
style.element_create('down', 'image', imgDown)

style.layout('up.TMenubutton', [('Menubutton.border',
  {'sticky': 'nswe',
   'children': [('Menubutton.focus',
     {'sticky': 'nswe',
      'children': [('Menubutton.up', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}),  # replace the indicator by up arrow
       ('Menubutton.padding',
        {'expand': '1',
         'sticky': 'we',
         'children': [('Menubutton.label',
           {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})]})]})])

style.layout('down.TMenubutton', [('Menubutton.border',
  {'sticky': 'nswe',
   'children': [('Menubutton.focus',
     {'sticky': 'nswe',
      'children': [('Menubutton.down', {'side': 'right', 'sticky': ''}),  # replace the indicator by down arrow
       ('Menubutton.padding',
        {'expand': '1',
         'sticky': 'we',
         'children': [('Menubutton.label',
           {'side': 'left', 'sticky': ''})]})]})]})])

var = tk.StringVar(root, 'a')
option = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var, *list('abcde'))
option.configure(style='down.TMenubutton')
menu = option['menu']
menu.configure(postcommand=lambda: option.configure(style='up.TMenubutton'))
menu.bind('<Unmap>', lambda ev: option.configure(style='down.TMenubutton'))
option.pack()

root.mainloop()
```